# On a SharePoint 2013 hosted machine, can workflow manager and workflow manager client reside on same server?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, workflow-manager

We have an application server, and from control panel i see Workflow manager 1.0 and workflow manager client 1.0 installed on same server where SharePoint is hosted.

Will this have any impact on workflows or SharePoint functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow Manager can be Installed on SharePoint server as well as non SharePoint servers. Installation of WFM will not impact the SharePoint rather it is added functionality if connected to your farm.

IF WFM installed on a server then you will see both WFM and WFM client installed. More over you need to install WFM Client on all remaining SharePoint servers in farm. I.e if you have 3 servers in farm and on 1 server WFM installed then you have to install WFM client on remaining two servers otherwise SharePoint will not able to communicate with WFM.

Comment: Hi Waqas, our sp2016 farm have 2 wfe, 2 app and 2 search topology.  I found both WFM and WFM client installed on 2 App server. All other servers do not have wfm and client installed. However we cannot find any problem.

Also I cannot find any official source saying wfm client should be installed on all SP servers. I need some support for my production change. Could you briefly tell me what the client do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is certainly possible. Workflow Client is required on all SharePoint servers in the farm. Workflow Manager can be installed on 1, 3 or 5 servers either on SharePoint servers or externally on non-SharePoint servers.

This will not impact existing SharePoint functionality, it will simply add SharePoint 2013 workflow functionality after you configure the integration between SharePoint and WFM.